# C# How can I clear all foreign key references in order to save the deletion of the primary key record to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, database

When I perform a delete on a primary key record it deletes the foreign key record and saves the change, but when it goes to delete the primary key record it won't let me save the deletion of the primary key record to the database. Instead it gives the following error:

> Error: The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this key still exist. [ >Foreign key constraint name = FK_PERSONID ]

According to what I've seen online I should be able to disable the EnforceConstraints either through code or through the DataSet Designer View. After doing it through code failed  I tried changing the EnforceConstraints to False in the DataSet Designer View. It still gives the same error. I tried editing the foreign key constraint to do a Cascade Delete and it still gives the same error.
Trying to do it with only the Cascade Delete without the code got the same error. 
This is the portion where I perform the deletes.

```
    bizDocStartupDBDataSet1.EnforceConstraints = false;

    BizDocStartupDBDataSet1.EmployeeTitlesRow oldEmployeeTitlesRow;
    oldEmployeeTitlesRow = bizDocStartupDBDataSet1.EmployeeTitles.FindByPERSONIDCOMPANYID(currentPersonID,1);
    oldEmployeeTitlesRow.Delete();
    this.employeeTitlesTableAdapter.Update(this.bizDocStartupDBDataSet1.EmployeeTitles);
    this.Validate();
    this.employeeTitlesBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.bizDocStartupDBDataSet1);

    this.peopleProfilesBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    SaveData();
    bindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Enabled = true;
    bizDocStartupDBDataSet1.EnforceConstraints = true;
```

The SaveData function is just the standard save with a refilling of the table, but the change to the datatable can't be saved to the database because there are still references to the Foreign Key.

How do I clear out all the references to the foreign key after the key with the foreign record has been deleted so I can save the deletion of the primary key record to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys are used to prevent records from getting orphaned, so getting rid of the foreign key is only a solution when you didn't need it in the first place.  Having said that, you'll have to cascade your deletes and you start with the record in the table that contains the foreign key, delete that FIRST, then delete the record with the primary key.  You may have to make two dataadapters the way you're doing it, but ideally you'd do this all with a stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have binded tables be sure you are not delete records from the primary table unless you don't use them anymore.

if there is another table that contains a foreing key of the record you are trying to delete it you will have that problem.

Delete those record that are foreign keys of that record you want to delete and then at last delete that record you actually want to delete.

So i guess you should be careful of what you are trying to delete. Hope it helps!

And for the last question: you will have to delete all the records that are foreign.

Answer (score 0):

EnforceConstraints is a property of a C# DataSet object.  Modifying this value will not affect the structure or behaviors of your database.

Cascading delete is one way to solve your problem -- triggers are another.  But as a general rule I don't believe you should rely on automated deletes in the database.  I think it is better to use a stored procedure to manage this delete by finding all dependencies and remove them first, and then going ahead with the delete from the primary key table.  This way, you know exactly what's going on in your database.

I'm surprised that you continued to get a FK error after modifying the FK with cascading delete.  Maybe post the exact error and your updates to the table and we can have a better grip on what's happening?